# Скрипт, убирающий рекламу, появляющуюся перед игрой

Tags: javascript, css

Здравствуйте! Через iframe вставляю игру с другого сайта. Проблема в том, что перед запуском игры там проигрывается реклама. Подскажите, пжл, скрипт, который поможет ее убрать. Уже перепробовала кучу способов... Вот ссылка на страницу с игрой http://games-forbaby.ru/mishki/1244-mishki-pchela-i-medved.html

Comment: Никак. Спецификация iframe не позволяет "частично во времени" отображать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя повлиять на содержимое iframe использующего домен **не совпадающий с Вашим**, ни с помощью js, ни с помощью css.
Можно не пытаться это сделать.